# Get page properties, system properties and all children nodes with properties for type [mgnl:area] for magnolia cms

Tags: magnolia

I would like to write a script for a page in the website workspace in Magnolia that would list:

- system properties of the page
- page properties
- all children nodes with properties for all [mgnl:area] of the page

I have tried using the NoteUtil  from info.magnolia.jcr.util but I get all the children of the given node including those of type [mgnl:area] and [mgnl:page] and no properties.

```
VersionManager vm = VersionManager.getInstance();
Session session =  MgnlContext.getJCRSession("website");
root =session.getNode(path);
Iterable<Node> iterator=NodeUtil.collectAllChildren(root);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this one:

```
info.magnolia.jcr.util.NodeUtil#collectAllChildren(javax.jcr.Node, org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.predicate.Predicate)
```

and basically pass your own Predicate there, if you don't want to filter anything than pass true or similar.

Cheers,

Hope that helps,